# angularjs directive validation unique email check before send

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### html

```
<input type="email" data-input-feedback="" data-ng-model="user.email" data-unique-email="" required="required" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
```

### js

```
.directive('uniqueEmail',function (User) {
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        restrict:'A',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                /*
                 Is there a way to check if it's a valid email ?
                both ngModelCtrl.$valid and ngModelCtrl.$error.email doesn't work 
                */
                User.isUniqueEmail(viewValue).then(function(data){
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', !data.email);
                });
                return viewValue;
            });
        }

    };
});
```

so is there a way to check if it's a valid email
before sending the value to the server ?

### UPDATE

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push
```

using push() here to run it as the last parser, after we are sure that other validators were run

so only if required and email validation are passed
do the call to check for unique email

### END UP

```
.directive('uniqueEmail',function (User) {
        return {
            require:'ngModel',
            restrict:'A',
            controller:function ($scope) {
              $scope.isValidEmail = function(){
                  return $scope.form.email.$error.email;
              }  
            },
            link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                var original;
                // If the model changes, store this since we assume it is the current value of the user's email
                // and we don't want to check the server if the user re-enters their original email
                ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
                    original = modelValue;
                    return modelValue;
                });
                // using push() here to run it as the last parser, after we are sure that other validators were run
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    if (viewValue && viewValue !== original ) {
                        if(scope.isValidEmail(viewValue)){
                            User.isUniqueEmail(viewValue).then(function(data){
                                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', !data.email); 
                            });
                        }
                        return viewValue;
                    }
                });
            }

        };
    });
```

### With compile and priority

```
.directive('uniqueEmail',function (User) {
        return {
            require:'ngModel',
            restrict:'A',
            priority:0,
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    var original;
                    // If the model changes, store this since we assume it is the current value of the user's email
                    // and we don't want to check the server if the user re-enters their original email
                    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
                        original = modelValue;
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(original);
                        return modelValue;
                    });
                    // using push() here to run it as the last parser, after we are sure that other validators were run
                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                        if (viewValue && viewValue !== original ) {
                            if(scope.isValidEmail()){
                                User.isUniqueEmail(viewValue).then(function(data){
                                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', !data.email); 
                                });
                            }
                            return viewValue;
                        }
                    });
                    scope.isValidEmail = function(){
                        return scope.form.email.$isvalid;
                    }  
                }
            }
        }    
    });
```

it still doesnt work the value of scope.form.email.$isvalid
is unreiable and seems out of date :(

Comment: I think the $parsers implementation is currently sync, so it will not wait on the promise. Your results may be odd. The best you can do is just verify that it looks like an email.

Comment: See my comments in the answer i provided. This could be priority issue.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the `parsers` is important. I am not sure but your parser may have got registered before the inbuilt parsers and hence gets fired first.

Maybe if you splice the `$parsers` array and insert your parser at `0` it may work.

Comment: Thanks for the point my goal is validated unique email after required and email are passed (I put push for that reason) The strange thing is this console.log(ngModelCtrl.$parsers) get me [] instead of at least ng-require and ng-email ...

Comment: Ok, the reason could be directive priority. Look at priority documentation for directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile and set appropriate priority on your directive.

Comment: I've updated con priority and compile (but I think priority works also in a link block)